# How to disable metro bundler "auto pop-up"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When building react native apps metro bundler automatically pops up on new terminal window (if it is not running already).

**Problem**
When configuring CI tool (Jenkins), for beta and release deployments, this behavior is blocking, because we want to setup 2-3 different applications and if one instance of Metro Bundler was opened before, other application build with fail.

I've checked all "Run Script" phases on XCode project. There isn't any script which opens Metro Bundler.

Does we really need metro bundler server if configurations is not debug? If no, then how to disable it on during release builds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Start Packager step in the build process, it looks like you can set RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER to a non-empty value to disable the packager. This worked for me running a release build using react native 0.61.5.

Comment: How did you do this @NemesisRidiculii ?

Comment: @Naren In my case, I was trying to automate a build using Jenkins, so I added this to the step in my pipeline:
`environment{   RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1   }`
If you're using xcodebuild, you could also export it on the command line before executing the command.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store and it solved the issue for me.

`To configure your app to be built using the Release scheme, go to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme. Select the Run tab in the sidebar, then set the Build Configuration dropdown to Release.`

Answer (score 0):

if you use node.js the metro bundler will run inside the terminal , another alternative is call the metro bundler before running the app `react-native start` should open the popup, and in the build it should not open a new one

Comment: I am talking about Release build type, i run offline bundle script before compiling, so Metro Bundler is unnecessary during release build. I need it only in development!

Comment: Oh ... dear... that would be impossible, metro bundler, is the "program" (more like a packager) that, "converts" the javascript code to a single file wich is then interpreted by react native in your smartphone , every time you do a build the packager needs to run to be able to make the files for the ios/android app (even in a release build, it stills need the packager)https://medium.com/@rishabh0297/role-of-metro-bundler-in-react-native-24d178c7117e)

Comment: What about react-native bundle? I able to bundle offline build for release. What i am looking for, to not run development server during release process, instead bundle js code during or before release process, without dev server

Comment: @Rafael Hovsepyan Hi, were you be able to solve this?